# 'Click Button' acts differently in Firefox compared to Chrome?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Fields Populate in 'Chrome' but not 'Firefox'???**

1. The test case requires a postcode to be imputed into a 'Email' text field and then user will have to click on the 'Search Button'

**Chrome:** 
1. Chrome browser works fine, when the test script inputs an email address and then clicks the search button the next fields 'Address Line 1, 2... etc) get populated.

**Firefox 'The Issue'**
1. If the same test listed above get executed in firefox, upon clicking on the search button the fields 'Address Line 1, 2... etc) DONT GET POPULATED?

2. I have tried Thread.sleep, timeouts etc
3. I have also tried many types of click 'normal click, js click, action move and click etc.
4. The button gets 'Clicked' by the script, its just that in firefox the next fields dont get populated once the button has been pressed.

**Has anyone came across this issue before?**

[image]

**Button code:**

```
<button class="btn search_btn col-sm-2 ng-binding" type="button" ng-click="SearchAddressByPostCode($event,true)">Search »</button>
```

**Section code:**
[image]

Comment: Show `HTML` of "Search" button

Comment: @Andersson  now attached to ticket

Comment: @Phil_P85 can you let us know which selenium version you are using and which firefox version you are using. Try upgrading the Selenium version and downgrading the Firefox version. Could be some issue with Selenium Library.

Also, do you get an error message when you entered an invalid or empty postcode and click search?  Just trying to identify where the issue is?

Comment: @Gaurang Shah  thanks for the reply, im using: Selenium:3.0.1 Firefox50.1.0,
**What version of firefox do you recommend?** thanks again